# Usage of "fanny" as verb

Tags: meaning, british-english, slang, colloquialisms

I am not a native English speaker, hence please bear with me.

I understand that *fanny* means *mess around* and *waste time*. Can someone suggest how I might make a sentence which uses *fanny*, as an equivalent to

> Don't waste my time.

Also, it would be great if someone can explain under what circumstances we can replace *wasting time* with *fannying about*.

Comment: In British English it has altogether a different meaning, an extremely rude one, and I'm not quite sure that *fanny* in American English means what you say. Have you checked in a dictionary?

Comment: Also, @Mari-LouA http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fannying

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes I have. In British sitcom, The Thin Blue Line,  Detective Inspector Derek Grim uses the phrase "fannying about" very often. I am not sure if using the phrase "fannying about" is more rude than saying "don't waste time". Should this phrase always be avoided?

Comment: OK, "fannying about" (note the letter -Y missing in your post) would be a lot less ruder than *fanny*, but it is still slang, and if the context is inappropriate, *fannying about* might not be understood by everyone or considered highly inappropriate. The negative connotations of *fanny* have probably softened over the years, but it still has some shock value (you heard the expression being used in a British sitcom).

Comment: ODO has a usage example: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fanny

Comment: @Kris I understand the usage "fannying about", but it's more like "wasting time", how to use "fannying" when it's like "don't waste my time". How should portray this meaning, using fannying? Though, as Mari mentioned, it seems that it is better not to use "fannying".

Comment: @Mari-LouA: The way I mostly hear "fanny" used in American English matches the "Silly Yanks" definition of http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fanny, which says that it means "bum". I wouldn't consider it a rude word. One common combination is "fanny pack", which is a bag that is carried with a strap around the waist: http://www.amazon.com/Travel-Fanny-iPhone-Pocket-Green/dp/B00JQL1RV0.

Comment: @RetoKoradi But in BrEng *fanny* is a euphemism for vagina. There, I said it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Yeah, I saw the BrEng definition when I looked it up... had kind of guessed it already from your original comment. Good to know that we can't use it in the UK.

Comment: I'd say _fannying about_, on a scale between _mucking about_ and _fucking about_, would be nearer to _fucking about_ than _dicking about_ would be. Not the sort of thing to say in a job interview, but OK in the pub as long as you are friends with the person you say it to, otherwise you may spend some time _fannying about_ in an A&E ward. They all still fall short of _cunting about_ though.

Comment: @Frank you should post that comment, slightly modified/censored, but at least you are a true BrEng speaker.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The answer from Kris explains it, but I felt _British informal_ was perhaps a little 'weak' in describing how _fannying about_ can be used. When used 'aggressively' it applies the pejorative _fanny_ to the _fannying abouter_ not to the process of _messing around_; _Stop fannying about_ is short for _Stop messing about, you fanny_.

Comment: @Frank Kris's answer doesn't show how the expression can be used in an everyday sort of context. It's carefully phrased, academically worded and doesn't really convey its meaning.

Comment: The phrase "fannying about" is not offensive and can be used without concern.  As Sumit says, there is a British sitcom in where the word is used extensively which would give you a good idea of the kind of sentences you can construct.

To give you a useless example, as soon as I've added this comment I'm going to loudly say "Time to stop fannying about and get on with some work" then go get a coffee.

Comment: @DaveM I agree, us native speakers are comfy with _fannying about_ because we know when to use it and when not. Native speakers are comfy enough to call each other _An old fanny_ (or worse) as a term of endearment but for someone that doesn't understand the nuances required to use those sort of phrases, they are best steered clear of outside of friends who understand what you mean or are trying to mean, especially as there are a number of other phrases that mean the same but don't carry the risk of being misunderstood.

Comment: @Frank.  Aye, I agree.  I'm thinking of the hilarious misunderstandings caused by the different meanings of "fanny" in the US and the UK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*fanny* is defined in Collins English Dictionary at [CollinsDictionary.com](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fanny) as

> (taboo, British) the female genitals
>
> (mainly US & Canadian) the buttocks

It is used frequently to describe someone in a not very polite manner

> You are a fanny! (often as *complete and utter fanny*)

'Taboo' seems a little strong for *fanny* as it can be used in a relatively friendly manner, particularly in the phrase *fannying about*. Collins notes that *dick* used to be 'taboo' but no longer is. *Dick* can also be used in the same way: *dicking about*.

Using *fanny* as a verb, still carries all the baggage and you need to be cautious with your usage.

Amongst friends *stop fannying about* means no more than *stop messing about*, however when used aggressively the meaning goes back to the original and becomes *stop messing about, you fanny*. Calling someone a *fanny* aggressively is only slightly less offensive than calling them a *cunt*.

You can use it self-referentially of course.

> *Sorry I'm late, I had to fanny about with my bike to get it started*

but you wouldn't use that as an apology for arriving late for an interview.

Given the opportunity for someone to misunderstand the intention of the word *fanny* in *fannying about* I would avoid it in all situations where you are talking to people you do not know very well. It's generally OK with your friends (if they accept it) but it would not be the sort of phrase you'd use in a more formal setting.

Do bear in mind that both *Dick* and *Fanny* are still fairly common names in the UK, so if you hear someone using the word *dick* or *fanny* you need to comprehend what they mean. It's quite possible to say "I met a Dick/Fanny last night" meaning "I met someone, whose name is Dick/Fanny, last night" or it could mean "I met someone, who I really didn't like, last night"

Other 'messing aboutery' terms, listed in the order of what I consider least likely to offend to most likely to offend, the first three being not offensive at all.

- fooling about
- messing about
- mucking about
- bumming about<sup>[i]</sup>
- farting about (fart : passing wind from the anus)
- dicking about
- arsing about (arse : bottom/anus)
- fannying about
- fucking about
- cunting about<sup>[ii]</sup>

[i] *bumming about* is the US meaning of *bum* (vagrant, loafer, (UK:tramp)) and means much the same - 'hanging about doing nothing much'.

[ii] rarely used in a friendly way.

Comment: Why the vulgarity? And what has *dick* got anything to do with *fannying about*?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Because _fanny_ is vulgar. _dick_ is slang for penis, _fanny_ is slang for female genitals. _fannying about_ and _dicking about_ are the same thing and both are vulgar both mean _acting like a dick/fanny_. Neither are synonyms for _messing, mucking, fooling_ they are vulgar terms. They are not terms to be used lightly.

Comment: Look at the edit, if you feel I've distorted your post then rollback. I think the message of its vulgarity still comes through pretty strongly.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sumit did say he understood _fanny_ to mean _mess around and waste time_, _dick_ is used in the same way. I thought it would be helpful to show that not only is _fannying_ not quite what he thought, but _dicking_ is also pretty much the same thing. However, if you feel that the inclusion of _dick_ was too much, I'll go along with that.

Comment: Also: someone who is a *Fanny* is a coward. *Stop being such a fanny*. **Also** Fanny is not a common name in the UK any more, not for the under 60s anyway.

Comment: Also: no one would ever say *I met a fanny last night*. They would say *I met a dick last night*. Fanny is never used as a derogatory term for a person, where as dick is.

Comment: +farting about - has overtones of ineffectuality.

Comment: As a native British speaker, calling somebody a fanny is not *remotely* as offensive as calling them a cunt. "Cunt", at the moment, is about the most offensive word in the English language. Calling somebody a fanny isn't much more offensive or loaded than calling them an idiot or a dick; calling them a cunt is a highly offensive statement, implying deep loathing and derision.

Comment: Also, Dick is a relatively rare name in the UK these days: most Richards abbreviate their name to Rich or Rick, precisely because dick has offensive connotations. Fanny is an extremely rare name: there might be a few old people who still use it but that's about all.

Comment: The scale is wrong, fanny about is not vulgar at all.  See my answer as to why.

Comment: In the US we would say "bumming around" rather than "bumming about" to mean general loafing.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Some of us old people are still alive, you know. The answer is to a question from a non-native speaker, had it been someone who identified themselves as a native speaker the answer would be quite different. Us native speakers know when to say _fanny_ and when not to. Imagine walking up to a group of lads on the lash, on a Friday night, and telling them to _stop fannying about_, when what you mean is _stop messing about_. The latter you'd probably get away with, with just some verbals, _fannying about_ could get you a beating. There is a difference and we know it, Sumit didn't.

Comment: @android.weasel How did I miss _farting about_! I'll edited it in. Thanks.

Comment: @Frank Advising that the term may cause offence is wise and helpful. Advising that it will cause as much offence as "cunt" is completely wrong. Telling a bunch of drunk people to stop fannying about is probably fairly safe; telling them they're a bunch of cunts is likely to land you in hospital.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I've not been in the UK for many years so maybe things have changed a bit. Certainly the TV shows I watch on-line have a lot more (of what used to be) swear words in them. Surely were not reduced to only one offensive word now, where's the fun in that?

Comment: @Liam - you assert that "Fanny is never used as a derogatory term for a person": clearly you have not been to the West of Scotland (Glasgow, for example...) recently!

Answer (score 6):

The verb *fannying (about)* is intransitive. As such it is not used in a sentence like "Don't waste **my** time," where the verb is transitive.

[**fanny**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fanny) on ODO:

> verb (fannies, fannying, fannied)
>   [no object] (fanny about (or around)) *British informal*
>   Mess around and waste time:
>   *they were fannying about in the street*

Compare, *loafing*, a similar intransitive verb.

Answer (score 1):

The term 'fanny about' has nothing to do with female genitals but instead comes from naval slang.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanny_Adams

'Sweet Fanny Adams' aka 'Sweet FA' and thus 'fanny about' means to do nothing.

This is why on your scale of rudeness it is not anywhere near as vulgar as 'dicking about' because while fanny can refer to genitalia in this instance it is not.

The word fanny on its own can be considerably more rude, or it could refer to a person's name. Context is everything.

Comment: While the etymology may be different, it has certainly merged into a single idea and in formal context would certainly be taken as rude regardless.

Comment: No it hasn't, at least in England there is a significant difference in where the terms can be used. Hence why it can be used in an early evening sitcom that goes out to families. I am an English, native English speaker so I understand the subtlety rather than simply comment on it as others have clearly done.

Comment: I agree that "fanny about" isn't particularly offensive but your reasoning doesn't work. Most people will be exactly as offended by "fanny about" as by "fanny" and will neither known nor care about the etymology of the situation.

Comment: only the sort of people who would be offended by the word cockpit!  It is someone's name, you can't declare a name to be arbitrarily offensive.

Comment: @JamesRyan - the Wikipedia article you linked to is certainly very interesting: I hadn't heard this explanation of the original of the term "Sweet F.A.". It may well be the true origin - but I don't see any explicit confirmation that "fanny about" is derived from "Sweet Fanny Adams".

Comment: @AAT technically you might be right, but I haven't seen anything showing that it is derived from the other meaning either.  How else do you explain that the term is massively less offensive than the term fanny on it's own?  This term comes from an era where people had this as their name, the popularity of slang for vagina is much newer.

Comment: @JamesRyan - I personally find the "Fanny Adams" explanation quite convincing, and it is good to raise it as an alternative source, but I don't see proof one way or the other. (I agree it seems less offensive than 'fanny' as a noun, but that must be custom rather than etymology.) Anyway I think David Richerby's point - that some, possibly many, people will link the verb to the noun and so hear it as being as offensive as being called a fanny - is valid, and the etymology doesn't change that.

Answer (score 0):

It can only really be used in that context followed by about:

---

fanny about

fannying about

---

Here's an example

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l63RSzqpwHQ